# Combine date and time is very slow, how to make it efficient?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, time, ssms, concatenation

This is my code

```
concat(CONVERT(varchar(10), cast(cast(cast(DATE1 as int) as char(8)) as date), 101),
```

Above part is creating date format and then concatenating below with:

```
', ',
convert(varchar(5), (convert(time, left(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), TIME1), 6), 2)
+ ':' + substring(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), TIME1), 6), 3, 2)
+ ':' + substring(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), TIME1), 6), 5, 2))), 108))
```

This returns the time.

Combining the two in same line outputs as mm/dd/yyy, 13:00

I am converting original fields where date is written as yyyymmdd and time is written as 5-6 digits, 71200 (7:12, but seconds always 00).

This takes significantly long, so I would like a way to make the code more efficient.

A note, I am concatenating date with 4 different time columns, so maybe that's why it is taking long?

Comment: Doing string manipulations are always going to be slow.  Try using DATEADD instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using DATEADD instead of string manipulations:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, TIME1%10000/100, 
  DATEADD(HOUR,TIME1/10000, 
    CAST(CAST(CAST(DATE1 as int) AS char(8)) AS datetime))

TIME1 / 10000 should give you the number of hours.  71200 -> 7 
TIME1 % 10000 should give you the number of minutes * 100. 71200 -> 1200 
TIME1 % 10000 / 100 will give you the number of minutes.  71200 -> 12
```

If you are querying this data often (more often than you are inserting/updating it), or you care more about query performance than updating/insert performance, then you should consider making a persisted computed column on this table so that you don't have to do these calculations at query time.  You can then also index the column which will help immensely if you regularly filter based on the datetime.

Comment: getting this error:

`Msg 9810, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.`

Comment: `DATEADD(MINUTE, TIME1%10000/100, DATEADD(HOUR,TIME1/10000, CAST(CAST(CAST(DATE1 as int) AS char(8)) AS date)))` is the code

Comment: Yes, try casting the original date to a datetime.